# how to set display on countdown timer (javascript)

Tags: javascript, timer

I used the snippet below to create a countdown timer.

```html
<script>
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2024 15:37:25").getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }


  }, 1000);
</script>
```

How do I set the output (display) like so:

1. If the remaining time is still above 1 month, then display only the month.
2. If the remaining time is under 1 month, then display only days,
3. If the remaining time is below 24 hours, display the hours and minutes
4. If the remaining time is below 1 hour, display the minutes and seconds.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about how are you defining a month? 28, 30, or 31 days?  Have you attempted anything thus far?  Dealing with dates and times can be complex; you may want to consider leveraging a third party library that abstracts out some of the complexity for you...

Answer (score -1):

first add a calculation for number of months left
then add a function that limits the times like so

```
const displayRemaining = () => {
    if (/* there are months remaining */) return months + " months";
    if (/* there are days remaining */) return days + " days";
    if (/* there are hours remaining */) return hours + " hours";
    if (/* there are days remaining */) return minutes + ":" + seconds + " m:s";
    return "you have gone back in time or smth idk";
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem at hand. The hardest/ most complicated part i. e. doing date arithmetic is skipped completely.

Comment: @Mushroomator If there are days remaining: if (days < 0)? Am I missing something here?